# Only TLS1.2 protocol can be enabled in SP800_131 strict mode

Tags: java, websphere-8, watson-conversation

WAS 8.5.5.2

Applications that were previously working are now failing because external Watson Services accessed by the WAS based applications only support TLS1.2.  After updating the security configuration of the WAS we are receiving a runtime error trying to reach external services.

We've configured WAS to support TLS1.2 in strict mode, but it appears we're missing additional configuration updates, and looking for advice where to specifically look to resolve this issue.  Can provide additional information if needed:

Application Exception:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only TLS1.2 protocol can be enabled in   SP800_131 strict mode
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pb.a(pb.java:43)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pb.(pb.java:77)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:232)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.(qc.java:268)
    at    com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:4)
    at     okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:270)
    at    okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)
at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)
 at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:192)

Comment: The stack suggests you are using okhttp3, which as far as I know bypasses WebSphere SSL.  So the question is how to make okhttp2 use TLSv1.2.